# Marginal distribution can't be equal to zero?

Tags: probability

I know that Marginal distribution should correspond to the axiom, so the sum $$P(X=x)=\sum_y  P(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_y \sum_x P(X=x|Y=y)*P(y)=1$$

Why can't, for example $P(X=1)=0$?

Comment: Where did that $=1$ come from?

Comment: Why can't it be zero? It very well can be zero.

Comment: it can be zero or any real number between 0 and 1 as the 1 in your rhs of the equation is incorrect. The correct expression would be $\sum_x \sum_y P(X=x|Y=y)*P(y)=1$

Comment: @sasha yes, forgot the sum

Comment: @gbox no now its not equal to lhs.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(X=x)+P(X \neq x)=\sum_x \sum_y P(X=x|Y=y)*P(y)=\sum_y P(X=x|Y=y)*P(y)+P(X \neq x)=1$$

All the above are trivially one and the same thing. But $P(X=x)$ is just the probability of random variable $X$ taking value $x$ it can very well be any real number in the range $[0,1]$.